# Excel 2016: How to Validate Data Against a User-Defined Function

Tags: excel, validation

In Excel, I'm trying to validate URLs against a user-defined function. I've tested the formula, and it works. But now I need to refer to this function in a cell's data validation. I've done some Google searching, and it seems I need to enter the function in a cell, name that cell, and refer to the named range in the data validation. So I defined the function with `ValidateUrl(ByVal UrlToTest As String) As Boolean`. I put that in cell E50 and called that cell "validateurlcell." Next, I went to the cells I want to validate, opened up the data validation dialogue, and entered "Custom" in the Allow field and, in the Formula field, I entered "=validateurlcell."

But here's my problem. What do I put in validateurlcell for the argument for ValidateUrl (i.e. what do I put for UrlToTest)?

This is my first time trying to use a UDF for validation, so maybe I messed up a step, or maybe I misunderstood the instructions i read on Google?

Thanks!

Comment: I dont think your approach is possible. What I'd do is try to establish a connection to the url inside an On Error Resume Next, and if it generates an error you know the validation has faied. Does that make sense?

Comment: In E50 you should put a formula that will evaluate to True or False.  Then, in the CF dialog, you test to see if E50 contains True or false

Comment: Ron Rosenfeld, your answer made it clear! Works now! Thanks a ton! You should add this as an answer so I can check it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to use your UDF as a Data Validation criteria:

- Put your UDF in, for example `E50` but write it in such a way that it returns a Boolean  eg:

---

```
E50: =ValidateUrl(url_string)
```

where your function has been written to return the Boolean

- As the Data Validation Formula, use something like

---

```
=E50=TRUE
```

That should work